# React router: How to update component outside route on param change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

When a url param change, I need to update two components, but one of them is outside the route with the param. The routes in App.js are like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
       <Route exact path="/" render={ (props) =>
         <Home products={this.state.products} } 
       />
        <Route path="/products/:product" render={ (props) => 
          <Product {...props} /> } 
        /> 

        <Route path="/"  render={ props => 
            <ProductHistory {...props}/>  }
         /> 
  </div>   

</BrowserRouter>
```

The ProductHistory which is always visible has links pointing to products, like:

```
<Link to={`/products/${product.product_id}`}> {product.name}</Link>
```

When following such a link, the Product component is updated using ComponentWillReceiveProps method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.match.params.product !== this.props.match.params.product){
```

But how do I update the ProductHistory component at the same time when the product param change? Since it isn't within the `/products/:product` route,  checking `this.props.match.params.product` in ProductHistory's componentWillReceiveProps results in `undefined`.
(**edit** - and withRouter doesn't help, since it already is within a route, but a different one: "/")

In componentWillReceiveProps I could use `location.pathname` to check that the path begins with "/product", and I could find the param by `substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1`.

**Edit:**  But I also have to compare the current id param with the next product id param to avoid unnecessary updates. But when clicking the link, the url have already changed when componentWillReceiveProps fires so `location.pathname` and `nextProps.location.pathname` always match, so it updates unnecessarily  (repeated api calls).

So I would have to find a different solution - rearrange the routing in some way? The idea is that ProductHistory should always be visible though.

Comment: Why don't you put the `ProductHistory` component under `Product`? Why do you need separate routes for them?

Comment: But then it would only show on product pages, so I would have to duplicate it and put it on other routes and I think that would cause problems.

Comment: If your `ProductHistory` depends on the `:product_id`, then it belongs there. What would be the content of the `ProductHistory` if the user navigates to `/blah`?

Comment: The Product history shows visited products (stored in session), so each time a product is visited, the history needs to update with that product. Any other page would just show the stored product history.

Comment: List the state into a parent component which holds both `Product` and `ProductHistory` components. Use state on the parent and pass a `setState` callback from the parent to the `Product` page and on `componentDidMount` call it with proper product data. Pass the state of the parent to the `ProductHistory` to render the list. Use `Switch` from react router in the render method of parent component.

Comment: Okay, I will look into this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the Route simply like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={ (props) =>
      <Home products={this.state.products} } 
    />
    <Route path="/products/:product" render={ (props) => 
      <Product {...props} /> } 
    /> 
  </Switch>
  <ProductHistory />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And then in the **ProductHistory** class you use the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) HOC

> You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest
>   **Route**'s match via the **withRouter** higher-order component. **withRouter**
>   will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped
>   component whenever it renders.

example:

```
class ProductHistory extends Component { ... }

export default withRouter(ProductHistory);
```

or using decorators

```
@withRouter
export default class ProductHistory extends Component { ... }
```

With this you will be able to access match, location and history through props like this:

```
this.props.match
this.props.location
this.props.history
```

Comment: When I add withRouter , and alert JSON.stringify(this.props.match)
 in componentWillReceiveProps, the data is empty: {"path":"/","url":"/","isExact":false,"params":{}}

Comment: @Galivan that doesn't mean it is empty. Usually if you didn't use withRouter that would simply give you undefined. That would be empty data. That means that you're in the route "/"

Comment: No, I get the same result even without "withRouter" if doing  JSON.stringify(this.props.match) - since productHistory already has the router (registered on <Route path="/" ) so it has access to match, history and all that, but it doesn't have any connection to the product/:product route. But I do have access to location.pathname.

Comment: @Galivan you need Switch from react-router-dom for some route switching and then you can always render the ProductHistory outside like you want and since the component is inside the BrowserRouter it must work. I have a bunch of projects doing stuff like this and they all work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this, there is a new solution afforded by hooks, in the form of [useRouteMatch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) in [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

You can lay your code out like João Cunha's example, where `ProductHistory` is not wrapped within a `Route`. If the `ProductHistory` is anywhere else but inside the `Route` for products, all the normal routing information will seemingly give the wrong answer (I think this might have been where the problems with `withRouter` arose in the replies to João's solution), but that's because it's not aware of the product route path spec. A little differently from most MVC routers, React-router-dom won't be calculating the route that matched up front, it will test the path you're on with every `Route` path spec and generate the specific route matching  info for components under that `Route`.

So, think of it in this way: within the `ProductHistory` component, you use `useRouteMatch` to test whether the route matches a path spec from which you can extract the params you require. E.g.

```js
import { useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
const ProductHistory = () => {
  const { params: { product } } = useRouteMatch("/products/:product");
  return <ProductList currentProduct={product || null} />;
};
```

This would allow you to test and match against multiple URLs that might apply to products, which makes for a very flexible solution!